# why my dishes are always over satiating?

Tags: flavor

whenever I cook dishes its always over satiating, I believe it has too much umami on it, and whenever I cook I always feel like being full already by just tasting while cooking. Like its too delicious and you cant eat more of it. Is there a way to get rid of that over satiating taste?

Comment: Sounds like the dish may just be too rich.  Try cooking lighter foods?

Comment: I always have the same results in every dish I do, mostly with soups, its hard to balance out flavors when umami is already concentrating in my dish.

Comment: and I've been cooking like this for a plenty of years, and I'm so frustrated. I tried lots of tips, like balancing it with something sour, like a splash of vinegar or calamondin but my dish just gets worse.

Comment: Then maybe you need to try some new recipes.  As-is, I don't think anyone can give a better answer to this question because we don't know what you're cooking or how.  If this is an issue across multiple kinds of foods, then it sounds like there may be a problem with your technique (chronic mismeasurement of richer ingredients, for example), but again, without more details I don't think we can provide a good answer.

Comment: I'm very sorry for that, but heres one dish I tried,http://www.panlasangpinoymeatrecipes.com/beef-pares-recipe.htm and followed the recipe as is. The dish turns out over satiating.

Comment: That appears to be a very hearty dish-- something I would expect to be pretty filling.  Perhaps you simply have a smaller appetite than the dishes you cook are designed to feed.

Comment: Maybe you're doing everything right? It's delicious and doesn't sabotage your portion control :) What do others say about the food?

Comment: Two things that may, maybe, help - check your room temperature and water intake.  When I'm feeling like the scent is enough, can't eat or can't eat much, sometimes the problem is caused by the body craving something thin and cool to drink, not hot rich food.  Either that or drinking a glass of water reminds the body the stomach is *actually* empty not matter what the nose thinks, not exactly sure.  Or else try just diluting the food with water or milk or something (depending on recipe) to cut the flavor concentration.  I don't know if these will help, but they may.

Comment: @rackandboneman others said the same thing, over satiating.

Comment: @Megha I tried adding water while cooking, and flavors are just concentrating.

Comment: This question is unanswerable without any indication what *my dishes* are.

Answer (score 3):

"Too delicious, and you can't eat more of it":

I don't see the "too delicious" part as a problem. Delicious is good.

"Can't eat more of it", as others have pointed out, sounds like it is just too heavy, or too rich. So, as others have also pointed out, it might help to cook some less heavy foods. In general, fish, tofu, and vegetables (especially raw or steamed) tend to be lighter and less filling than meats and heavy cheesy or buttery sauces.

Depending on your cuisine tradition, however, substituting different food items may not be an appealing option. If most of the dishes that you and your family find acceptable happen to be on the heavy side, at least you can serve them along with other things in the meal to add variety, like plenty of plain rice or other simple grain, green salad, and/or steamed, pickled or raw vegetables and maybe a refreshing cold beverage or fresh fruit.

Comment: Yes,I never had problems with light foods, in other cases like stir frys i never had bad dishes, but when it comes to soups and stocks thats where I get this over satiated feeling just by cooking. Whenever I will cook heavy dishes, can I lessen some ingredients with higher MSG content? Like if it needs 1tbsp soy sauce I will reduce it to 1/2tbsp? would that even work?

Comment: @user58559, That sounds like a good idea to me. Not sure about *other* msg containing ingredients, but certainly the soy sauce is really all about flavoring, and I can't imagine any terrible consequences from just reducing it from 1tbsp to half a tbsp. The flavor will just become a little less intense, and also less salty. You can always add a dash of plain salt, if you feel the need.

Comment: https://www.chowhound.com/post/ill-effects-rich-food-297377
this is how I feel about food.

Answer (score 1):

There is a real point here. If, while cooking, you repeatedly season by tasting the current (accumulated) mixture, you may become habituated, especially to the level of salt, and go too far. If you retain a sample of the unseasoned mixture, and compare the flavor to that, you get a better idea of what it's like for a guest, tasting it for the first time.

Answer (score 1):

Interpret, rather than take literally, what your tasting spoon tells you.

Our taste sense is rather heat dependent - and straight-from-the-pan heat seems to make many people under-taste salt and sugar, and over-taste bitter compounds (which would call for compensating with ... you guessed it, salt and sugar). On top of that, you will get a "first-bite taste" that doesn't take accumulating flavours (the kind that only develops after a couple of bites) into account. Also, some sauces will be less tongue-coating (due to lower viscosity, especially of fats!) and thus appear less intense than they are at pan heat.

Try intentionally seasoning so your tasting spoon *seems* underseasoned but reasonably balanced. Alternatively, don't taste a pan-fresh spoon but actually plate (or let cool on the spoon) a small portion.